# How to run an application in Terminal?

Tags: kubuntu

I have installed a application (MATLAB) in Kubuntu and it is installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

If I type the name of the program in Terminal, it's not running and says that did not find that command. When I go to that folder where it is installed and drag to the terminal and then it starts working.

Can anybody help me here as I am new user of Linux.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH` (check with `echo $PATH`)? Are you typing `matlab` (lower case) or `MATLAB` (upper case)?

Comment: Copy and paste your terminal screen, including the command you entered and the error message reported, into your question.